# Google Drive and MS Access

Tags: ms-access, google-drive-api

In a function attached to a click, I need to upload a Word document to Google Drive (id gmail), which has been saved in a folder synchronized to my Google Drive via the Google Drive Desktop API

What I would like to do is automatically generate a link to share with access role - 'anyone' - 'comment', this for each NEW file that is added and sent to any address mail via Outlook.

Below is the code I use for the mail response with some criteria. I would need to add the code relating to the upload to Google Drive and the acquisition of link to share.

```
Private  Sub Command29_Click ( ) 
Dim olApp As  Object 
Dim olMail As  Object 
Dim strPath As  String 
Dim strLocation As  String 
Set olApp = CreateObject ( "Outlook.Application" ) 
Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem ( 0 ) 
Dim strsubject As  String 
Dim sMsgBody As  String 
Dim a, T As  String
 
 
Dim i As  Integer 
Dim v As  Variant 
Dim db As DAO.Database
 Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
 Set db = CurrentDb
 
 
a = Me ! [ MS no ] 
T = Me ! [ Title ]
 
'Replace yourTable with the name of the table that has Undergoing field " 
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset ( " select [Email id] from [profile details form updated] where [Undergoing MS number] Like' * " & a & " * ' " , dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly )
 
With olMail
 
 
    If  Not  ( rs.BOF And rs.EOF )  Then
        rs.MoveFirst
    End  If 
    Do  Until rs.EOF
        v = Split ( rs! [ Email id ] , "," ) 
        For i = 0  To UBound ( v ) 
            v ( i ) = Trim $ ( v ( i ) ) 
            If Len ( v ( i ) )  Then 
                .Recipients.Add v ( i ) 
            End  If 
        Next
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing 
    Set db = Nothing
 
    strsubject = "Received your manuscript for publication, www.ijpbs.net" 
    sMsgBody = "Respected author," 
    sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "<br> <br>" 
    sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "Ref manuscript number MS:" & a & "" 
    sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "<br> <br>" 
    sMsgBody = sMsgBody & "We have received your research / review article“ " & T & " ”and the copy right form and would be categorized under" & sb & ". We have allotted manuscript number MS " & a &"for your article. For further correspondence, kindly use this manuscript number only. We would be sending your manuscript to our reviewer (Reviewer 1) for evaluation. We will send the acceptance decision within 7-10 working days" 
    sMsgBody = sMsgBody & " <br> <br> "
    .to = M.Subject 
    = ( strsubject ) 
    .HTMLBody = ( sMsgBody )
    .Display
End  With
 
Set olMail = Nothing 
Set olApp = Nothing 
End  Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, implementing the Google Drive API in VBA is way too broad for a question here

Comment: kindly help me in getting code